# DataSet best practices?

Tags: .net, database, dataset

I am new to dotNet so...  in my next project it is req. of me to use DataSet (desktop app). I did understand most of it, but... simple question: Is it better to create one dataset for entire project (150+ tables, 90+ stored procedures...) or is it more advisible to create, should I say, smaller datasets for each app module(performance is very important !!!) Most of App logic is implemented in DB (stored procedures, triggers... DB is ORACLE).

Comment: My best practive for `DataSets` would be: **avoid them**. Use an ORM instead (that turns your database row into a nicely usable .NET object, so you can work with properties on an object, rather than having to mess with column names and type conversions and stuff like that...)

Comment: Strongly typed datasets also are .Net Objects and you don't have to mess with type conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against having 1 dataset for everything as each time you instantiate it you would have to create ALL of the tables.

I would recommend logical group.

Comment: Why you must instantiate it more than once? You could share it application wide.

Comment: You don't want to load your entire database into memory.......that just doesn't scale...and is prone to a plethora of issues...

Comment: Depends of the size of your database or the part of it that you need constantly(f.e. masterdata) and also the number of possible users. It might be faster and with less traffic to use only one instance for all users instead of reloading all data on every postback.